# Redirect to IdP with added querystring parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using IdentityServer4 and have configured an OpenId Connect provider. What I want to do is pass in a username to the provider as part of the querystring so that the provider pre-fills in the username field. I have both ADFS and Azure AD providers and would like this functionality to work with both. Is this possible and if so how?

In the `Challenge` method on `ExternalController` I've added what I think should work but it doesn't do anything:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Challenge(string provider, string returnUrl, string user)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) returnUrl = "~/";
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) == false && _interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl) == false)
    {
        throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
    }
    if (AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName == provider)
    {
        return await ProcessWindowsLoginAsync(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Callback)),
            Items =
            {
                { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                { "scheme", provider },
                { "login_hint", user }
            }
        };
        return Challenge(props, provider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you're looking for using the [`OnRedirectToIdentityProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/OpenIdConnectEvents.cs#L34) property of the [`OpenIdConnectEvents`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/OpenIdConnectEvents.cs) class:

> Invoked before redirecting to the identity provider to authenticate. This can be used to set ProtocolMessage.State that will be persisted through the authentication process. The ProtocolMessage can also be used to add or customize parameters sent to the identity provider.

You hook into this process via the [`AddOpenIdConnect`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectExtensions.cs#L17) function, which is called when using `services.AddAuthentication` in `Startup.ConfigureServices`. Here's an example of what this might look like for your requirements:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        ...

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
            {
                if (ctx.HttpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue("user", out var stringValues))
                    ctx.ProtocolMessage.LoginHint = stringValues[0];

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

Most of this is just the boilerplate code for adding authentication, OIDC and registering an event-handler for the event detailed above. The most interesting part is this:

```
if (ctx.HttpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue("user", out var stringValues))
    ctx.ProtocolMessage.LoginHint = stringValues[0];
```

As your `Challenge` action from your question gets `user` from a query-string parameter, the code above reads out the `user` query-string parameter from the request (there could be more than one, which is why we have a [`StringValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringvalues?view=aspnetcore-2.1) here) and sets it as the `LoginHint` property, if it's found.

Note: I've tested this with https://demo.identityserver.io (which works, of course).